# The Ring of Locally Holomorphic Functions around a Fixed Point in $\mathbb{C}$ is a PID

Tags: complex-analysis, principal-ideal-domains

I saw this statement mentioned the other day, and I have some questions about what we are actually saying. What do we mean by a "locally holomorphic function around a fixed point in $\mathbb{C}$?" My interpretation of it would be to fix some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and say that we are looking at functions $f$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on some open set $\Omega$, where $z \in \Omega$. But we could also mean it where, instead of taking open sets, we could take the more restrictive $\epsilon$-neighborhoods around $z$. I've heard "locally" being used in both these contexts before.

There's also some ambiguity around the phrase "fixed point." I think it means what I say above, but it could also mean we are looking at functions $f$ that fix some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $f(z_0) = z_0$.

And after this is clarified, how would we begin to go about proving that this ring is a PID? From similar questions asked on this site, it seems that where the function is $0$ plays an important role in determining ideals, but I'm not exactly sure of the specifics involved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you see the statement? I guess that the statement is about the **gems of holomorphic functions** at $0$ consisting of *equivalence classes* of holomorphic functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ where $\Omega$ is an open set containing $z_0$ and two such functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ and $\tilde f:\tilde\Omega\to\mathbb C$ are equivalent if the coincide on a third open set $z_0\in U\subseteq \Omega\cap\tilde\Omega$. It does not matter if one considers only open balls with centre $z_0$.

Comment: It was on an old Princeton oral exam. It was from the students recollection so it may very well be misremembered or something like that. They built up to the case of $\mathbb{C}^n$, but started off in the case $n = 1$. They then started talking about the zeros of the function and how that relates to the ideals.

Comment: in one variable the result is just the local form of holomorphic functions, so for example if the point $z_0=0$, the nonzero proper ideals are just $z^n\mathcal O, n \ge 1$ where $\mathcal O$ is the ring of holomorphic germs at $0$

Comment: “Fixed” here means that you specify a particular point. This has nothing to do with fixed points of a mapping.

Comment: @Conrad, I see that $z^n\mathcal{O}$ are all proper ideals in the ring, but how do we know that they are the only ones?

Comment: Because if $I$ is a non zero proper ideal any $f$ in it must vanish at the origin as it cannot be invertible as a germ, and taking $n$ the lowest order of vanishing for some (non zero $f$ so $n$ finite) it's easy to see that $z^n=fh$ for the germ $h=z^n/f$ which is holomorphic as $f$ vanishes precisely of order $n$ so the ideal contains $z^nO$ and then it is that since no $g$ in it can have lower zero order by our choice of $f$

Comment: @Conrad, Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: happy to be of help - in higher dimensions, one uses Weierstrass preparation theorem to obtain info about the structure of the germ ring; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem