# Is The sub ring $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I am attempting to prove (or disprove) that $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ is Noetherian, where $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ is the subring of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ consisting of functions holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Note : $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ represents the ring of formal power series with coefficients in the field of complex numbers.

Firstly, I recognize that in the ring of smooth function $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ if we consider the family of ideals
$$I_n = \left\{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \>\Bigm|\> f \text{ vanishes in } \left]-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right[\;\right\},$$
we obtain an increasing chain that does not stabilize.

Why does this work for $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and not for $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$?

Here's my explanation:

Using the principle of analytic extension, if $f$ is analytic and $f=0$ in an open set, then it is the null function.

Now For smooth functions, we can consider the ideal $I_n$ because it is not equal to the trivial ideal $\langle 0 \rangle$ since a smooth function is not necessarily analytic.

However, in $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$, the functions are holomorphic, which is equivalent to being analytic. Consequently, we would have $I_n = \langle 0 \rangle$.

So, is there another approach or is the one I mentioned sufficient to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$ is Noetherian?

Edit:

Additionally, one can consider the ring of smooth maps, denoted as $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, instead of $\mathbb{C}\{z\}$, which is more general.

Comment: Wait, $\mathbb C[z]$ is usually the ring of polynomials. Presumably, you mean something else, since otherwise, they'd all be holomorphic everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It was a typo! Typically, it is $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$.

Comment: Hello. My complex analysis is a bit rusty, but I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648379/473276) answers your question positively. Conrad sketches an argument in the comments there. Basically, the ideals just line up with the order-of-vanishing at $0$. The argument is quite similar to how you can prove that $K[[X]]$ itself is a PID when $K$ is a field!

Comment: Thank you very much, I see it.